# Modern reference on separation principle in stochastic optimal control

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-processes, optimal-control, hamilton-jacobi-equation

I am looking for a modern reference on the separation principle in stochastic optimal control, which states that under certain conditions the optimal control can be found by deterministic optimization, setting the noise terms in the dynamics to zero.

(There is also a separation principle for state observation, but I'm not interested in that, I assume I know the exact state).

The original research article references in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_principle are mostly outdated (I actually read a review from the 80's once, unfortunately I can't find it anymore, that said there are a lot of mistakes in the claims and proofs of the initial works) and some are difficult to read / written from an engineering perspective as opposed to a mathematical perspective.

Does anyone know of mathematical books about stochastic optimal control theory (preferably written by mathematicians for mathematicians) that covers the separation principles but also discusses exact (in numerical limits) methods for situations when no  separation principle holds?

I'm not saying at all that mathematicians are the better optimal controllers, indeed, I found quite a few mathematical books about stochastic optimal control from a PDE perspective, that didn't even mention any separation principles.

Comment: Maybe it is hard for you to find a good book since what you are looking for is called ``Certainty Equivalence'', not the separation principle (which is the splitting of estimator and controller design). Essentially any book on stochastic control talks about this, but If you want a classic mathematical book, look at Linear Stochastic Systems by Peter Caines.

Comment: @WalterJ the references I could find didn't paint such a clear picture. I just typed "Stochastic control book pd" into google and accessed the books/lecture notes that are not behind a pay wall. The first didn't include "certainty equivalence" at all, the second said "Note that for the quadratic cost, the optimal feedback
function for the partially observed case is the same function as in the
completely observed case, where we have merely replaced the system
state by its estimate! This is called certainty equivalence", i.e. the exact opposite of what you said

Comment: (I meant "...pdf" in the previous comment). The specific book you mention does seem to contain certainty equivalence in the way you use it(all I can find out through the google books preview is that the term appears on page 678 in the section "Complete state observation"). However, the book seems to be restricted to the time discrete case and it also doesn't seem to give much weight on certainty equivalence, judging from the length of the section. If you have the book, do you know if it gives a detailed and extensive discussion of when exactly certainty equivalence applies?

Comment: And finally, here are some books that contain neither "certainty equivalence" nor "separation principle" (I believe so at least, most are not openly accessible, so I base my claim on openly available indices or  Google books searches): https://math.berkeley.edu/~evans/control.course.pdf (Evans) https://books.google.co.uk/books?redir_esc=y&id=4Bjz2iWmLyQC (Fleming-Soner) https://books.google.co.uk/books?redir_esc=y&id=IYZF1Fci9n8C& (Krylov) https://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/4852/appendix.pdf?sequence=2&isAllowed=y (Shreve-Bertsekas)

Comment: It almost feels like there is a whole gang of mathematicians that reinvented optimal control without ever learning about the linear algebra basics that the control theorists are so fond of.

Comment: I am not sure what you are after, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_control#Certainty_equivalence . The idea is very basic, even for us control theorists, and therefore barely discussed. The best way to learn it is to work out some LQR/LQG problems yourself.

Comment: @WalterJ For example, http://homes.esat.kuleuven.be/~jwillems/Articles/JournalArticles/1981.2.pdf take 7 pages to derive a most basic form of certainty equivalence. And even so, they are not at all starting from scratch, resorting to "is well-known" for all sorts of  Ricatti equation stuff. I basically want something like that paper but (1) assuming no background in control theory (2) presenting a more general result (non-Gaussian noise, jumps). I believe that certainty equivalence may not be discussed in current research articles, but there must be a proper textbook on it, right?

Comment: @WalterJ A further aspect that I wanted to learn about are situations where separation/certainty equivalence does not hold but optimal controls are still linear

Comment: Regarding your last question, this certainty equivalence principle does not generally hold, a nice example (still, with linear state-feedback indeed) is called LEQR/LEQG (due to the exponential utility), i.e. $\mathbb{E}[\mathrm{exp}(x)]$ instead of $\mathbb{E}[x]$, for more information see this paper by its founder http://pages.stern.nyu.edu/~dbackus/Exotic/1Robustness/Jacobson%20IEEE%2073.pdf

Comment: @WalterJ  but optimal controls aren't linear there, right?

Comment: Hi: I haven't been successful but if you can get anything by Wonham, that might explain it. His book was too expensive for my taste but I'm pretty sure he's one of the gurus when it comes to the separation principle. Certainity equivalence is somewhat different ( unless it has two meanings )  in that it says that when you have a quadratic optimization problem, you can take expected values of the random variables in the problem and the problem remains the same from an dynamic programming perspective. There's a good paper on it whose title escapes me. I'll try to find it and send a link.

Comment: Theil also has a famous paper but I remember reading this one and following it. H.A. Simon, “Dynamic Programming under Uncertainty with a Quadratic Criterion Function,“ Econometrica, 24 (1956), 74–81.